# Is the following logic right or wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis

I have a convex function (since its double derivative is greater than zero). The function is defined over the real values The first derivative of the function is a polynomial of 3rd degree (that is it involves $x^3$ term). Since the first order derivative has three possible roots. Is it possible that more than one root is real? I think it is not possible because the first derivative is an increasing function on the real values and hence it can not have more than one real roots. Is this right reasoning? Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One characterization of convexity is that the derivative is nondecreasing; see Rockafellar's *Convex Analysis*. So you cannot have two or three roots, your reasoning is correct.

Edit: Some details added.
Your cubic can only have 1 or 3 real roots (because they come in complex conjugate pairs). Now suppose you would have three real roots, $a<b<c$.
If $f$ is convex, then $f'$ is increasing (a.k.a. "nondecreasing") and so
$f'(a)\leq f'(u)\leq f'(b) \leq f'(v)\leq f'(c)$, where 
$a<u<b<v<c$. But then $f'$ is identically $0$ on the interval $[a,c]$, which is absurd since a cubic has only 1 or 3 real roots.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So can we write the close form formula for finding that real root? I have seen formula which involve two roots which appear to be conjugates of each other while the third root seems to be real but I am not sure whether my assessment is right. Can you provide a formula?\

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843518/solving-a-cubic-polynomial-equation

Comment: I am sorry but I can not understand it. Can you please mention which steps/formula you are refferring to?

Comment: I thought you inquired about solving cubic equations (how to solve them). I am now assuming you want more details about the proof which I added in the main answer.

Comment: Strictly Increasing function$\ne$nondecreasong! This is a small detail but important, a function who is nondecreasing can have infinity roots($f(x)=0$). If $f$ is polynomial degree $1$ or greater can't have infinity roots (obviously) because there could be only finite *points* where the function is non-decreasing and non-increasing, if $f$ is convex then $f'$ is *strictly* increasing, something more powerful than non-decreasing. You answer has nothing wrong in it(because it is polynomial degree 3), I just wanted to point out that something stronger exists in this situation